# Keyboard shortcut to access "lightning menu" in MS Excel for macOS

Tags: ms-office, keybindings

How do I access this menu with the keyboard?

I think I tried all the intuitive ways:

- It's not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (which is what it is on Windows).
- It's not <kbd>Shift</kbd>.
- It's not GUI or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>.
- It's not <kbd>Alt</kbd> / <kbd>Opt</kbd>.

[image: Screenshot of an MS Excel spreadsheet with a single cell selected and showing an icon with the letters 'ABC' and a lightning bolt; the drop-down menu for this icon shows 'Overwrite all cells in this column with this formula']